# Changing button's visibility after opening a new form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms. Form1 and Form5. Form1 has 2 buttons which open Form5. I want to change the visibility of Form5's button after it is shown. I have set Form5 button's modifiers to public and I've also tried this code below but it's not working:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form5 fr5 = new Form5();
    fr5.button1.Visible = true;
    fr5.ShowDialog();
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form5 fr5 = new Form5();
    fr5.button1.Visible = false;
    fr5.ShowDialog();
}
```

Edit: I've set button1.Visible = true; in Form5 Load event.

Comment: "...not working..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? There is no `Form2` in your code.

Comment: please make your question more clear

Comment: You should definitely check the answer to your previous question. Making your controls public is a bad idea in the first place and it's not the case of your problems.

Comment: And would you please format your questions the right way? Also asking a ton of similar questions without waiting at least 1 day for the answer on previous ones is not how people do here.

Comment: @Jazb Not working because there is no error messages and the button visibility is not change after the  new Form shown.

Comment: @jitendrajoshi I actually have 2 button in each form, let's say the button name is save and edit. I want each time I click form1's edit button, form2 will show and the visibility of form2's edit button change to true and the save button to false. In Form1 load event I have set save button to true. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @ymdred16 I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough. I am new with stackoverflow. Thank you for your advice. Also, I've checked your answer on my prev question. I created two separates questions because I think it's two different case and different solution.

Comment: @CybFyr It's definitely about the same problem. So do you want to be able to use your Form1 when Form5 (or Form2) is opened? The solution depends on your answer :)

Comment: @ymdred16 I want Form1 to be unable to use when Form5 is opened. Because, I don't want user accidentally click the same button that open Form5.

Comment: @CybFyr Then you should go with `Form5.ShowDialog(this);` and make use of created form Owner property :)

Comment: switch from ShowDialog to simply .Show() after that change button property and call  form5.Invalidate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. :) I have solved the problem by changing the code like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form5 fr5 = new Form5();      
    fr5.Show(this);
    fr5.button1.Visible = true;
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form5 fr5 = new Form5();      
    fr5.Show(this);
    fr5.button1.Visible = false;
}
```